# How to add a shortcut to a command to the Cinnamon menu?

Tags: shortcuts, cinnamon

Is there a utility I can use to add an icon to the Cinnamon menu which runs a user-specified command, and as a bonus, displays a user-specified icon?

specifically I'm trying to add a command to open a virtual machine directly, without having to keep the terminal open.

```
VirtualBox --startvm <myMachineName> --seamless
```

works fine with `alt-F2`, but I'd rather have a short-cut so I don't have to type it out.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create a `.desktop` file to add your command to the Cinnamon menu.

First, create a little script eg: *In your home directory*

- Open your terminal and type:

  ```
  gedit /home/user/myvm.sh
  ```
- Type the following:

[image]

- Save the file in your home directory and change the permissions with:

  ```
  chmod 775 /home/user/myvm.sh
  ```
- Then you can create a desktop file, in the terminal type:

  ```
  cd /usr/share/applications
  sudo -H gedit myvm.desktop
  ```
- Add the following information:

[image]

- Save the changes and make sure the .desktop has the right permissions, in the terminal type:

  ```
  sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/applications/myvm.desktop
  ```

You can change the information according to your needs, in this case in the field **"Icon"** put your path to your custom icon, and this should be visible under the Cinnamon menu in the category **"System Tools"** with the name **"My VM"**.

[image]

If you want, you can add it to your cinnamon panel with right click in the icon **"My VM"** in the Menu, and then choose **"add to panel"**

[image]

Comment: beautiful instructions, the screenshots were not needed but very appreciated :)

Comment: As mentioned by [childno͡.de's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/897698/373707), using `~/.local/share/applications` won't need root privileges if you don't need to add shortcuts for all users.

Comment: Though I was aware of the entire process (I always use the `~/.local/share/applications` pointed out by James), for one app it didn't seem to work. The important step there was the `chmod`: the `.desktop` file in my case had `744` and didn't show up in the menu until I changed it to `644` as you described. That did the trick! Funnily, `755` works fine as well, seems it just does not like `744`…

Answer (score 53):

or you could just use the

```
cinnamon-menu-editor
```

(Also available by right clicking the start button, selecting `configure` and `Open the menu editor`.)

---

Tip: When adding a custom icon, be careful to locate the icon image somewhere you won't be likely to change in the future.

Comment: Make sure you put the entry IN A MENU (e.g. Programming).  If you put it in the root, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a gnome desktop link and place it in `.local/share/applications/`
for personal menu links.

Sigh: some installers install their desktop links into `.gnome/apps/`
so you might want to link them:
`$ ln -s .gnome/apps/*.desktop .local/share/applications/`

---

As pointed out by @roman-raguet https://askubuntu.com/a/232083/37280 place it into `/usr/share/applications` for all users

As pointed out by @mockfrog https://askubuntu.com/a/800605/37280 you might create this personal entry by `cinnamon-menu-editor` graphical tool. Run it with `sudo` for all-users

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for a simpler solution, then the following offers a GUI interface for adding custom launchers to your panel:

```
cd /usr/share/cinnamon/applets/panel-launchers@cinnamon.org/
./cinnamon-add-panel-launcher.py
```

Comment: This is different, I think. This will add shortcuts to your panel, but not to the menu, right?

Comment: No longer works in current version of Cinnamon.

Comment: Directory exists, but "cinnamon-add-panel-launcher.py" does not exist in Debian Jessie 8.6 / Cinnamon 2.2.16.