# How to add an own shortcut to a command to the Cinnamon menu?

Tags: menu, shortcuts, cinnamon

My question is just like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/232053/10802), except that I need to add a *Cinnamon* menu item for a *single user only*. It should be done as a part of the installation process (for an application installed privately in user's home directory) without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

For a single user you can put the desktop entry file in `~/.local/share/applications/`

Check out the specification for more info and an example:

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html

You can also check the location for all users in `/usr/share/applications` for examples.

Good luck!